# Asymptotic approximation of an integral.

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximate-integration

How to find the asymtotic approximation of this Fourier integral :
$$I[T]=\lim_{T->\infty}^{}\frac{T}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/T}^{\pi/T}d\lambda e^{iT\lambda}e^{Tf(\lambda)}.$$
$\textbf{Context}$ :
This is a simplification of the problem i have encountered in the context of statistical analysis of a physics problem (specifically counting statistics of particles flux between two reservoirs), where moment generating function for particle flux is given by as :
$$Z[\chi,T]=\frac{T}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/T}^{\pi/T}d\lambda e^{iT\lambda}e^{Tf(\lambda,\chi)},$$ 
with $f(\lambda,\chi)$ being the unconstrained (here $\lambda$ integral is used to impose a constraint) scaled cumulant generating function. Specifically I am interested in long time limit of the scaled cumulant generating function , 
defined as :
$$\lim_{T->\infty}=\frac{1}{T}\ln\big(Z[\chi,T]\big),$$ 
whether it is independent of $T$. This can be thought of as getting a long time limit moment generating function for a contracted (one variable being fixed) bi-variate probability distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding very naively,
and probably making
errors along the way,
I get that the limit does not exist
if $f(0) > 0$,
is zero if
$f(0) < 0$,
and depends on
$f'(0)$
if $f(0) = 0$.

Here is my fiddling,
replacing $T$ by $t$
and
$\lambda$ by $x$.

$\begin{array}\\
I
&=\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{t}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/t}^{\pi/t}dx e^{itx}e^{tf(x)}\\
&=\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy e^{iy}e^{tf(y/t)}
\qquad x = y/t\\
&\approx\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy e^{iy}e^{t(f(0)+(y/t)f'(0))}
\qquad\text{since } y/t \text{ is small}\\
&=\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{e^{tf(0)}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy e^{y(i+f'(0))}\\
&=\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{e^{tf(0)}}{2\pi}\dfrac{e^{y(i+f'(0))}}{i+f'(0)}|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\
&=\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{e^{tf(0)}}{2\pi}\dfrac{e^{\pi(i+f'(0))}-e^{-\pi(i+f'(0))}}{i+f'(0)}\\
&=\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{e^{tf(0)}}{2\pi}\dfrac{-e^{\pi f'(0)}+e^{-\pi f'(0)}}{i+f'(0)}\\
\end{array}
$